# Products/Items are not being added in the Cart in Django. How do I fix it?

Tags: django, django-models, cart, shopping-cart

I am new to Django and working on an ecommerce app. I have defined the products and users things. But I am stuck at the cart.

I have basically two apps in my project viz. `index` and `cart`. I have defined `TwoPieceSuit()` as a products' model in `index.models.py` and I have defined `Cart()` & `CartManager()` (just to manage cart properly if an anonymous user logs in the web, after adding the products in cart) in `cart.models.py`.

I have defined `two_piece_suits`, an attribute in `cart.models.Cart` as a `ManyToManyField` referenced to `index.models.TwoPieceSuit`. Now it basically works all the way, until I want to add up the `price`(s) of `TwoPieceSuit()` instances and save the result in `total` of `Cart()`, it does not add up the prices. Despite of `Cart()` instance having many (because of `ManyToManyField`) instances of `TwoPieceSuit()` containing the values in `price` attribute, it does not add up the prices when I call them to be added in my `cart.models.py`.

My **`index.models.py`** is:

```
import os
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify

def get_file_ext(filepath):
    base_name = os.path.basename(filepath)
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(base_name)
    return name, ext

def upload_image_path(instance, filepath):
    name, ext = get_file_ext(filepath)
    filename = instance.fabric + '-' + instance.lining + '-' + instance.buttons + '-' + \
            instance.button_hole_thread + '-' + instance.buttoning + '-' + instance.lapel + '-' + \
                instance.pockets + '-' + instance.vent + '-' + instance.contrasts + '-' + \
                    instance.trouser_pockets + '-' + instance.trouser_buttoning + '-' + \
                        instance.trouser_back_pocket + '-' + instance.trouser_turn_up + ext
    return "products/{filename}".format(filename=filename)

# Create your models here.

class Fabric(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Title")
    img = models.FileField(upload_to = 'fabrics/', null = True, verbose_name = "Picture")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class Lining(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Title")
    img = models.FileField(upload_to = 'linings/', null = True, verbose_name = "Picture")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class Button(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Title")
    img = models.FileField(upload_to = 'buttons/', null = True, verbose_name = "Picture")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class ButtonHoleThread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Title")
    img = models.FileField(upload_to = 'button-hole-threads/', null = True, verbose_name = "Picture")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class Buttoning(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Title")
    img = models.FileField(upload_to = 'buttonings/', null = True, verbose_name = "Picture")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class Lapel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Title")
    img = models.FileField(upload_to = 'lapels/', null = True, verbose_name = "Picture")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class Pocket(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Title")
    img = models.FileField(upload_to = 'pockets/', null = True, verbose_name = "Picture")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class Vent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Title")
    img = models.FileField(upload_to = 'vents/', null = True, verbose_name = "Picture")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class Contrast(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Title")
    img = models.FileField(upload_to = 'contrasts/', null = True, verbose_name = "Picture")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class TrouserPocket(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Title")
    img = models.FileField(upload_to = 'trouser-pockets/', null = True, verbose_name = "Picture")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class TrouserButtoning(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Title")
    img = models.FileField(upload_to = 'trouser-buttonings/', null = True, verbose_name = "Picture")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class TrouserBackPocket(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Title")
    img = models.FileField(upload_to = 'trouser-back-pockets/', null = True, verbose_name = "Picture")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class TrouserTurnUp(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Title")
    img = models.FileField(upload_to = 'trouser-turn-ups/', null = True, verbose_name = "Picture")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

FABRICS = []
LININGS = []
BUTTONS = []
BUTTON_HOLE_THREADS = []
BUTTONINGS = []
LAPELS = []
POCKETS = []
VENTS = []
CONTRASTS = []
TROUSER_POCKETS = []
TROUSER_BUTTONINGS = []
TROUSER_BACK_POCKETS = []
TROUSER_TURN_UPS = []

for item in Fabric.objects.all():
    FABRICS.append((item.title.lower(), item.title))

FABRICS = tuple(FABRICS)

for item in Lining.objects.all():
    LININGS.append((item.title.lower(), item.title))

LININGS = tuple(LININGS)

for item in Button.objects.all():
    BUTTONS.append((item.title.lower(), item.title))

BUTTONS = tuple(BUTTONS)

for item in ButtonHoleThread.objects.all():
    BUTTON_HOLE_THREADS.append((item.title.lower(), item.title))

BUTTON_HOLE_THREADS = tuple(BUTTON_HOLE_THREADS)

for item in Buttoning.objects.all():
    BUTTONINGS.append((item.title.lower(), item.title))

BUTTONINGS = tuple(BUTTONINGS)

for item in Lapel.objects.all():
    LAPELS.append((item.title.lower(), item.title))

LAPELS = tuple(LAPELS)

for item in Pocket.objects.all():
    POCKETS.append((item.title.lower(), item.title))

POCKETS = tuple(POCKETS)

for item in Vent.objects.all():
    VENTS.append((item.title.lower(), item.title))

VENTS = tuple(VENTS)

for item in Contrast.objects.all():
    CONTRASTS.append((item.title.lower(), item.title))

CONTRASTS = tuple(CONTRASTS)

for item in TrouserPocket.objects.all():
    TROUSER_POCKETS.append((item.title.lower(), item.title))

TROUSER_POCKETS = tuple(TROUSER_POCKETS)

for item in TrouserButtoning.objects.all():
    TROUSER_BUTTONINGS.append((item.title.lower(), item.title))

TROUSER_BUTTONINGS = tuple(TROUSER_BUTTONINGS)

for item in TrouserBackPocket.objects.all():
    TROUSER_BACK_POCKETS.append((item.title.lower(), item.title))

TROUSER_BACK_POCKETS = tuple(TROUSER_BACK_POCKETS)

for item in TrouserTurnUp.objects.all():
    TROUSER_TURN_UPS.append((item.title.lower(), item.title))

TROUSER_TURN_UPS = tuple(TROUSER_TURN_UPS)

class TwoPieceSuit(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Title")
    img = models.FileField(upload_to = upload_image_path, null = True, \
        verbose_name = "Picture")
    fabric = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = FABRICS, \
        null = True)
    lining = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = LININGS, \
        null = True)
    buttons = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = BUTTONS, \
        null = True)
    button_hole_thread = models.CharField(max_length = 100, \
        choices = BUTTON_HOLE_THREADS, null = True, \
            verbose_name = "Button Hole Threads")
    buttoning = models.CharField(max_length = 100, \
        choices = BUTTONINGS, null = True)
    lapel = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = LAPELS, \
        null = True)
    pockets = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = POCKETS, \
        null = True)
    vent = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = VENTS, \
        null = True)
    contrasts = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = CONTRASTS, \
        null = True)
    trouser_pockets = models.CharField(max_length = 100, \
        choices = TROUSER_POCKETS, null = True, \
            verbose_name = "Trouser Pockets")
    trouser_buttoning = models.CharField(max_length = 100, \
        choices = TROUSER_BUTTONINGS, null = True, \
            verbose_name = "Trouser Buttoning")
    trouser_back_pocket = models.CharField(max_length = 100, \
        choices = TROUSER_BACK_POCKETS, null = True, \
            verbose_name = "Trouser Back Pocket")
    trouser_turn_up = models.CharField(max_length = 100, \
        choices = TROUSER_TURN_UPS, null = True, \
            verbose_name = "Trouser Turn Up")
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places = 2, max_digits = 20, default = 99.99)
    slug = models.SlugField(null = True, blank = True, db_index = True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.fabric + self.lining + self.buttons + \
            self.button_hole_thread + self.buttoning + self.lapel + \
                self.pockets + self.vent + self.contrasts + \
                    self.trouser_pockets + self.trouser_buttoning + \
                        self.trouser_back_pocket + self.trouser_turn_up)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

My **`cart.models.py`** is

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from index.models import TwoPieceSuit

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

# Create your models here.
class CartManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id = cart_id)

        if qs.count() == 1:
            new_obj = False
            cart_obj = qs.first()
            if request.user.is_authenticated and cart_obj.user is None:
                cart_obj.user = request.user
                cart_obj.save()
        else:
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.new(user = request.user)
            new_obj = True
            request.session["cart_id"] = cart_obj.id
        
        return cart_obj, new_obj

    def new(self, user = None):
        user_obj = None
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_authenticated:
                user_obj = user
        return self.model.objects.create(user = user_obj)

class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null = True, blank = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    two_piece_suits = models.ManyToManyField(TwoPieceSuit, blank = True)
    total = models.DecimalField(default = 00.00, max_digits = 100, decimal_places = 2)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

My **`cart.views.py`** is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Cart, CartManager

# Create your views here.
def cart_home(request):
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    print(cart_obj.two_piece_suits)
    two_piece_suits = cart_obj.two_piece_suits.all()
    total = 0

    for item in two_piece_suits:
        print(item)
        print(item.price)
        total = total + item.price

    cart_obj.total = total
    cart_obj.save()

    return render(request, "cart/home.html", {})
```

Also, the screenshot that explains I have added the `TwoPieceSuit()` instances in the `Cart()` instance, using Django Administration Interface, is below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1RVy.png)

I will really appreciate if somebody helps, as I am tired of working it around.

Comment: `cart_obj.two_piece_suits.all()` returns an empty `<QuerySet []>`. But in Django Administration Interface, we can cleary see the `two_piece_suits` having the `TwoPieceSuit()` instances. Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out to solve my issue by looking at the official documentation, given below:

[The Django admin site | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models)

[Model field reference | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield)

[Related objects reference | Django documentation | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference)

and after doing a little more research I found a way to add the `TwoPieceSuit` instances in the cart using `from django.db.models.signals`. I would like to share the code so that whoever read this thread, might find it useful.

I don't know if it is a good way, because I did it indirectly. I actually defined a `pre_save_cart_receiver()` method and then connected it to `m2m_changed` signal by passing `Cart` model as sender. Now whenever I click any `TwoPieceSuit` instance in the `Cart` table in Django Administration Interface and click 'Save and Continue Editing', it actually updates the `total` attribute of the cart.

Below is the code for `pre_save_cart_receiver()`:

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

def pre_save_cart_receiver(sender, instance, action, *args, **kwargs):
    if action == "post_add" or action == "post_remove" or action == "post_clear":
        two_piece_suits = instance.two_piece_suits.all()
        total = 0
    
        for item in two_piece_suits:
            total = total + item.price

        instance.total = total
        instance.save()

m2m_changed.connect(pre_save_cart_receiver, sender=Cart.two_piece_suits.through)
```